# Using the value of a loop outside of the loop

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the data after I restrurce them in a loop.
So when the when the loop completes I could have a variable with the value in it so I could download it or whatever.

```
const handleData = async (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getsubs`, {

      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        getInput
      }),

    }).then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => {

      let len = res.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let subNum = i + 1;
        let start = res[i].start;
        let end = res[i].dur;
        let text = res[i].text;
        const secondsToHms = (start) => {
          //  ** starting restructuring the text **
          var h = Math.floor(start / 3600);
          var m = Math.floor((start % 3600) / 60);
          var s = Math.floor((start % 3600) % 60);
          var ms = Math.round((start % 1) * 1000);
          return (
            (h < 10 ? "0" : "") + h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s + "," + (ms < 100 ? "0" : "") + (ms < 10 ? "0" : "") + ms);
        };
        //  ** still in the loop **
        const inputToSRT = () => {
          return (subNum + "\r\n" + secondsToHms(start) + " --> " + secondsToHms(end) + "\r\n" + text + "\r\n\r\n");
          const srtData = inputToSRT();
          console.log(srtData);
        };
      }
      /*
          ** here the loop ends **
          ** Im looking to create a var here with the
             loop data stored in it so I could download it after **
      */
      let blob = srtData;
      //  ** download function outside the loop **

      // console.log(blob);
      // const download = () => {
      // Create blob link to download
      if (srtData != -1) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([srtData]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", `FileName.srt`);
        // Append to html link element page
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        // Start download
        link.click();
        // Clean up and remove the link
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I have tried adding the download function in the loop but it would download mulptie files with each loop instead of one with all the values

Comment: "`here the loop ends`" Except it doesn't end there. That bracket ends the `const inputToSRT` body.

Comment: Correct, but even when loop ends there I would get ref undefined because the download function is outside the loop

Comment: And If i include the download function in the loop it works but it would download each value alone instead all the values in one file

Comment: If you want the content of **srtData** outside of the loop, then declare it outside of the loop and modify it in the loop.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code structure; the indentation is working against understanding. Can you please edit it down so it's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue? A first step would be to abbreviate all the unnecessary local arrow function bodies as `...` e.g. `const secondsToHms = () => {...}` - For the purposes of your question I don't care exactly what that function does.

Comment: You also don't need to have secondsToHms inside of the loop, and **inputToSRT** can be modified and brought outside of the loop too like **inputToSRT = (start,end,subNum,text)** That won't fix your problem, but will clean up your code

Comment: "You also don't need to have secondsToHms inside of the loop"  If I move them out the loop It wouldn't work because I cannot ref the loop vars

Comment: @user19644379 why not? They are just passed as arguments much like how a function is treated.

Answer (score 0):

I moved **secondsToHms** outside of the loop as it isn't needed in there. I also moved and updated inputToSRT to accept arguments. Then I declared **srtData** outside of the loop so that the scope allows it to be modified in the loop then accessed outside of the loop.

```
const secondsToHms = (start) => {
    var h = Math.floor(start / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor((start % 3600) / 60);
  var s = Math.floor((start % 3600) % 60);
  var ms = Math.round((start % 1) * 1000);
  return (
    (h < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    h +
    ":" +
    (m < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    m +
    ":" +
    (s < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    s +
    "," +
    (ms < 100 ? "0" : "") +
    (ms < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    ms
  );
};

  const inputToSRT = (start, end, subNum, text) => {
    return (
      subNum +
      "\r\n" +
      secondsToHms(start) +
      " --> " +
      secondsToHms(end) +
      "\r\n" +
      text +
      "\r\n\r\n"
    );
  }
const handleData = async (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getsubs`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          getInput
        }),
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        let len = res.length;
        let srtData;

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let subNum = i + 1;
          let start = res[i].start;
          let end = res[i].dur;
          let text = res[i].text;
          srtData = inputToSRT(start, end, subNum, text);
        }

        let blob = srtData;
        // console.log(blob);
        // const download = () => {
        // Create blob link to download
        if (fetchData != -1) {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fetchData]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", `FileName.srt`);
          // Append to html link element page
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          // Start download
          link.click();
          // Clean up and remove the link
          link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
        }

      });
  }
};
```

Below is a test showing the variables passed and accessed outside of the loop.

```js
const secondsToHms = (start) => {
  var h = Math.floor(start / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor((start % 3600) / 60);
  var s = Math.floor((start % 3600) % 60);
  var ms = Math.round((start % 1) * 1000);
  return (
    (h < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    h +
    ":" +
    (m < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    m +
    ":" +
    (s < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    s +
    "," +
    (ms < 100 ? "0" : "") +
    (ms < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    ms
  );
};

const inputToSRT = (start, end, subNum, text) => {
  return (
    subNum +
    "\r\n" +
    secondsToHms(start) +
    " --> " +
    secondsToHms(end) +
    "\r\n" +
    text +
    "\r\n\r\n"
  );
}

let res = [
  {"start": 0, "dur": 1, "text": "test"}
];
let srtData;
let len = res.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let subNum = i + 1;
  let start = res[i].start;
  let end = res[i].dur;
  let text = res[i].text;
  srtData = inputToSRT(start, end, subNum, text);
}
console.log(srtData)
```

Comment: Your code should have `srtData` as an array, and append to it in the loop. Otherwise it just gets overwritten on each iteration and ends pointing to just the value from the final iteration.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes, you are correct. However, OP doesn't clearly state the needs of the data output so I'm basing this answer on their comments. Which really aren't clear either.

Comment: Figured it out thank to both you, first by looping at the end and getting the values as params `(inputToSRT(start, end, subNum, text))` inside the loop as @imvain2 suggested , and then declaring `srtData` as an array and pushing the text `(inputToSRT(start, end, subNum, text))` into them as @Darryl Noakes suggested , then I cleaned the arrays with a `[srtData.join("")]` to get rid of the array's commas.